Physics of cycling
I've been trying to model what the optimal gear is whilst a cyclist is cycling on some specific route, and I keep on encountering issues with how I've been doing the physics.
My initial approach was without gears and whatnot, just to get a feel for what I'm seeing because I haven't done physics in a while (I am a math student, this is purely a research project on the side).
Regardless, I went from the equation $F = ma$ to form:
$$\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{P - (F_g+F_{rr})v + F_d'v^3}{mv^2}$$
Just as a note, I'm assuming P is constant, $F_g$ and $F_{rr}$ are dependant on x, that's why I made the equation dependent on x and $F_d'$ is just $F_d/v^2$ so I could take out the v's.
The reason there ends up being $v^2$ down below is because of the chain rule for $dv/dt = dv/dx * dx/dt = dv/dx * v$, at least assuming my thinking is correct.
I seem to have digressed a bit. Anyway, from here I though the next logical step would be figuring out what speed of the cyclist is if we included gears, which at least as far as I've found, there exists some formulas for this, specifically:

$P = \tau \cdot \omega_{pedal}$
$v = G \cdot \omega_{pedal} \cdot r$
$\omega_{wheel} = G \cdot \omega_{pedal}$

Seeing as forming the equation out of $\omega_{wheel}$ removed all G's (that would be gear ratios, also $\tau$ is just torque), I opted for calculating the differential equation in terms of $\omega_{pedal}$ ending up with:
$$\frac{d\omega_{pedal}}{dx} = \frac{P - (F_g+F_{rr})(G\cdot r\cdot \omega_{pedal}) - F_d'(G^3\cdot r^3\cdot \omega_{pedal}^3)}{G^3\cdot r^3 \cdot \omega_{pedal}^2}$$
From there it really became a problem in optimization, that is, I was trying to restrict myself to human capabilities (assuming a pro I guess <70Nm for torque on a shorter path, <50Nm for longer paths I suppose, and cadence would optimally just be kept under 100RPM).
Regardless, I ran into an issue, after calculating $\omega_{pedal}$ in the differential equation, it seems I ended up with speed that doesn't really reflect pedalling, you can test this yourself by setting $P = 0$ and going down a slope like -1/3x or something like that.
Since I believe the entire system currently just converts all energy into pedalling, which obviously isn't correct.
I've been trying to come up with a logical solution for how to fix this issue, and the only idea I really had was replacing $\omega_{pedal}$ with $\omega_{wheel}$, but we can see how that turns out based off what I said up above.
I've had one other idea, which was to simply assume that the speed that comes out of these equations, using the formula $v = \omega_{pedal} \cdot G \cdot r$ ends up being the total speed of the cyclist in that moment, and then calculating the speed that comes from outside forces separately using the fact that $v = \frac{F}{m}dt$, since I can theoretically calculate the amount of time now using what I have, then calculating cadence and torque from $v_{total} - v_{outsideForces}$ or whatever, but I'm not really sure that's how that works.
Honestly I'm not really sure most of my work is correct, so I would be happy if anyone had any pointers. And I am ignoring wind for now simply because if I were to include it, it would be the next chapter in what I'm writing if I were to add it.


The top image shows what happens on a steep slope downwards, specifically the previously mentioned -1/3x graph, I am aware this is an extraordinarily steep slope, but I wanted to both see and showcase what the issue with the current equations seems to be, which is, that all the speed in the system seems to be directly attributed to pedaling even when none of it is coming from it (for that specific scenario $P = 0$).
The 2nd image on the other hand, shows the graphs for what happens on image 3, which is the path I'm technically trying to see what happens on, in my project thingy.
Top left graph is speed in m/s during the path, top right is cadence (RPM of the pedals), bottom left is the torque and the bottom right is the gear ratio we are in. I'd include the actual ratios, but there's 20 ratios that'd be cramped in there and it doesn't look legible unfortunately.
Specific information for the problem:
$$F_{d} = \frac{1}{2} * \rho * v^2 * C_d * A$$
$$F_{rr} = C_{rr} * m * g * \cos{(\theta(x))}$$
$$F_g = m * g * \sin(\theta(x))$$
Most of these are constant except for $\theta(x)$, which is just the angle of the path at any point on the road, that is, the graph below (p(x)) describes the path, and then $\theta(x) = \arctan(p'(x))$
Further information:

$P = 250$
$r = 0.34$
$A = 0.339$
$C_d = 0.665$
$m = 75$
$\rho = 1.225$
$C_{rr} = 0.0035$
Gears come in 2 pairs, $[39,53] / [11,12,13,14,16,18,20,22,25,28]$

The problem is trying to optimize speed based on:

$\tau = \frac{P}{\omega_{pedal}} \leq 70$
$N = \frac{60\cdot \omega_{pedal}}{2\pi} \leq 100$
$max_{G}(v)$ whilst the previous 2 conditions are met



Ok I'd just like to add since I wasn't really familiar with how adding images works, so I didn't add descriptions to them. The first image shows what happens when you are traveling down a slope of -1/3x with P=0
. Top right is cadence (that is RPM), bottom left is torque, gear shifts in the bottom right and speed in the top left.
The bottom image is just what it looks like on the specific path I picked, so it's not like it's all messed up, but it does still cause "jumps" and such as seen at about 30km into the path.

You can edit your question post to include the information describing the graphs. That's better than using comments because comments might be deleted someday by mods.

As far as I can tell, you haven't defined most of these quantities. What is $F_{rr}$? What is $F_d'$? Wjhat is $v$ and $x$ etc.? And what are you actually trying to model here? The behavior of the gear? The motion of the bicycle? What are the forces acting on? We need more info.

Of course, I had assumed most of this info I could leave out, sorry.
Uh, F_d' is just drag force / v^2, so I could take it out to simplify equations when writing them out in the post, F_rr is rolling resistance.
Specifically:
F_d = 1/2 * rho * A * v^2 * C_d
F_rr = C_rr * m * g * cos(theta(x))
x is just the position on the path, I can include an image I suppose, v is speed? velocity? sorry in my language they are the same word, so I'm not really sure what's the appropriate word here

Also, you mention a "slope like -1/3x"... If this is about the grade of the road, it's an extremely steep one. A 15% grade (1.15:1 slope) is one of the steepest roads you'll find in the US, and for long climbs, 4-5% (1.05:1 slope) are more typical.

@Meatius, again you should edit your question post to include necessary information instead of putting it in comments.

I've added the information to the post, should I also add the specific values I'm using for everything?
Also I know -1/3x is very steep, I was just trying to see what would happen to the rotations of the pedal on a downwards road, and -1/3x was good enough to get a visual of that information.

@march I'm trying to see what the optimal gear is at any point on a road whilst staying under specific parameters, that is as mentioned in the post, for example I want the torque to remain under 70Nm, and I want the rotations of the pedals (cadence) to remain under 100. The speed, cadence and torque graphs are add-ons so I could see what was going wrong at any point in time + they are good for calculating the amount of time the path will take, having all the information about the cyclist and such.

Not clear for me $~\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac {dv}{dx},v~$ and the drug force $~F_D=D~v^2~$ thus $~\frac {dv}{dx}=\frac 1m(\sum F+ D,v)~$

I'd like to suggest a different approach to lead off your investigation with, as follows.
Optimum power transfer between a driver (the cyclist) and a load (the pedals) occurs in the matched-impedance case. In the bicycling example this means that the gearing ratio must be set so the source is always operating at the peak of its power curve regardless of road slope, wind speed, etc. In this way you can avoid the ineffectiveness of trying to crank a load that requires immense torque and almost no RPM (geared too tall), or immense RPM and almost no torque (geared too short).
In this approach you begin with the fundamental biomechanical power curve of a typical human cyclist and then solve for all the different gearing ratios that match the peak of that curve for all the different possible loads.

I'm sorry, I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean, I've just edited the question, but my current approach is trying to solve for maximum speed based off all possible gear ratios, so at the start I solve all 20 differential equations, and then from there compare which ones have a low enough torque and cadence to fulfill the requirements and then pick the one with the highest speed.
From my understand your idea is to instead use torque and cadence as parameters to determine at what gear ratio and power we get the best speed?

oh wait, you mean as in distributing them instead so that I can determine whether I can crank up the cadence if torque is super low or crank up the torque if cadence is super low? I'll do that, thanks

It might help to consider a simplified system first.  I'm not sure if this is what you were going for, but let's suppose that a cyclist is able to "comfortably" apply torque at a rate that depends on the pedaling frequency $\omega_p$:
\begin{align*}
\tau = \tau_0 e^{-\omega / \omega_0}
\end{align*}
where $\omega_0$ is some characteristic frequency.  Let's also assume for simplicity that the "cyclist" is really a unicyclist, with a fancy gear-shifting unicycle, so there's only one wheel to worry about, and that the unicycle has a belt transmission that can accommodate arbitrary (continuous) gear ratios. If air resistance is the only source of drag (i.e. rotational friction is incorporated into $\tau(\omega)$) it isn't difficult to show that the equation of motion has the form
\begin{align*}
m\ddot x = -\gamma v - V'(x)+\frac{g(t)\tau_0 e^{-\frac{g(t)v}{r\omega_0}}}{\beta r}
\end{align*}
where $g(t)$ is the gear ratio at time $t$ (i.e. $\omega_p = g(t)\omega_{w}$), $\gamma$ is the drag coefficient, and $\beta$ is a dimensionless constant that depends on the moment of inertia of the wheel.
With these assumptions, we can now ask what (continuous) gear ratios $g(t)$ will optimize the speed of the cyclist?
Since we assume the cyclist has limitless reserves of energy the question is essentially equivalent to the following: What gear ratios $g(t)$ maximize the wheel torque at any and all moments of time.  For this, the answer is independent of $V(x)$ (the potential energy landscape), and depends entirely on the last term in the equations of motion.  Maximizing this, you will find a result roughly consistent with @niels_nielsen's answer: $g(t) = r\omega_0/v(t)$, where $\omega_0$ is the characteristic pedaling frequency (the relative rate of 'torque fatigue'.)

Sorry your equations are little bit confusing for me.
Those are my equations
Translation
$$ m\,\dot v=\sum F+f_r$$
Rotation (wheel)
$$I_w\,\dot\omega_w=\tau_w+f_r\,r_w$$
and the rolling condition
$$\dot v=r_w\,\dot\omega_w$$
where $~f_r~$ is the constraint force between the wheel and the road surface
you obtain that
$$ \frac{dv}{dt}=\frac {r_w}{I_w+m\,r_w^2}\,\left(\tau_w+r_w\,\sum F(~v,\theta(x))\right)\tag 1$$
where $~\tau_w=G\,\tau_p~$
to obtain the position of the bicycle you need this equation
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=v\tag 2$$
solving equations (1) and (2) you obtain $~v(t)~$ and $~x(t)~$ . from the rolling condition you obtain $~\omega_w=\frac{v(t)}{r_w}~$

$~w~$ Wheel
$~p~$ Pedal

